# Array.map : get the index of each element to use in the return function

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm looking for a command that returns the index of an element so I can use it in map functions.

Here's an example :

```
function myFunction() {
  var a = [4,7,9];
  //Looking for a way to return ["index 0 : 4", "index 1 : 7", "index 2 : 9"]
  //Only workaround found so far :
  var i = -1;
  Logger.log(a.map(function(el) {i++; return "index " + i + " : " + el}));
}
```

I'm sure there's a neater way with a command that would give me the element's index, but all my google searches have been fruitless so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it cleaner by three steps:

- Use the second parameter of callback passed to `map()` which is index of element.
- Use arrow function and implicitly return the value
- Use Template Strings instead of `+` again and again.

```js
var a = [4,7,9];
let res = a.map((x,i) => `index ${i} : ${x}`);
console.log(res)
```

In your above code you have created a function which doesn't make any sense. That function should take an array as a parameter and then log the value of that particular arr.

```js
const myFunction = arr => console.log(arr.map((x,i) => `index ${i} : ${x}`));
myFunction([4,7,9])
```

Answer (score 2):

Second parameter in callback function is `index` you can use that

```
  Array.map((value,index,this))
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = [4,7,9];
  console.log(a.map((v,i)=> "index " + i + " : " + v));
}

myFunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) already gives you the index. The callback gets three parameters:

```
a.map(function(element, index, array) {return "index " + index + " : " + element})
```

You don't need to declare all three (JavaScript isn't fussy about it), but they are there if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) since its second argument is an [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
console.log(Array.from([4,7,9], (x, i) => `index ${i} : ${x}`))
```

The overall idea is to use the 2nd parameter of map (which provides you with the current iteration index) and with that and the current value to construct your result.